# Updating a column depending on the value set in another column in the same row

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, sql-update

Got a table containing a `FLAG` column (any char) and two others fields `ESD` and `TD` (both date).
The `FLAG` column must be preceded by either the char `E` if `ESD` isn't null for that row, or followed by `T` if `TD` isn't null for that row.

**Note**

1. `FLAG` never null
2. `ESD` can be null `TD` can be null simultaneously or not.
3. `ESD` and `TD` can both be set on the same row. 
   In such case, the flag must be ExT, where x is the
   current flag value.

**Example**

*Before*

```
+-------+-------------+-------------+
| FLAG  | ESD         | TD          |
+-------+-------------+-------------+
|  V    | 2018/05/01  | (null)      |
|  D    | (null)      | (null)      |
|  V    | (null)      | (null)      |
|  V    | (null)      | 2018/06/31  |
|  V    | (null)      | (null)      |
|  D    | 2018/01/01  | 2018/08/31  |
+-------+-------------+-------------+
```

*After*

```
+-------+-------------+-------------+
| FLAG  | ESD         | TD          |
+-------+-------------+-------------+
|  EV   | 2018/05/01  | (null)      |
|  D    | (null)      | (null)      |
|  V    | (null)      | (null)      |
|  VT   | (null)      | 2018/06/31  |
|  V    | (null)      | (null)      |
|  EDT  | 2018/01/01  | 2018/08/31  |
+-------+-------------+-------------+
```

**Question**

What is the easiest way to get this result in SQL or PL/SQL ?

Comment: Are you really trying to update the value stored in the table; or just how it appears in the result set when you query the table?

Comment: I'm trying to update it in the table

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use concatenation and two case expressions:

```
case when esd is not null then 'E' end
  || flag
  || case when td is not null then 'T' end as flag
```

Demo with your data in a CTE (correcting as June doesn't have 31 days):

```
with your_table (FLAG, ESD, TD) as (
            select 'V', date '2018-05-01', null from dual
  union all select 'D', null, null from dual
  union all select 'V', null, null from dual
  union all select 'V', null, date '2018-06-30' from dual
  union all select 'V', null, null from dual
  union all select 'D', date '2018-01-01', date '2018-08-31' from dual
)
select
  case when esd is not null then 'E' end
    || flag
    || case when td is not null then 'T' end as flag,
  esd,
  td
from your_table;

FLAG ESD        TD                          
---- ---------- ----------------------------
EV   2018-05-01                             
D                                           
V                                           
VT              2018-06-30                  
V                                           
EDT  2018-01-01 2018-08-31
```

If you really want to update the value in the table then you can use the same thing in an update statement:

```
update your_table
set flag = 
  case when esd is not null then 'E' end
    || flag
    || case when td is not null then 'T' end;
```

but then the flag will be wrong as soon as a null date column is populated, and will be harder to recalculate when you need to. You should either just adjust this as you query it, optionally via a view; or add a virtual column that holds the generated value separately.

Answer (score 2):

Seems like a simple update using `CASE` statements?

```
UPDATE [table] SET FLAG = CASE WHEN ESD IS NOT NULL THEN 'E' ELSE '' END || FLAG || CASE WHEN TD IS NOT NULL THEN 'T' ELSE '' END;
```